# Name of anime with a substitute hero

Tags: ore-ga-heroine

Here is the story. The hero is a boy who likes a girl that ends up being a witch. When she is in trouble he tries to rescue her but get's beamed to a spaceship by another girl who needs his help. Before he can help her he gets summoned to another planet to fight an overlord dragon who is immune to magic. He then slays the dragon with a ray gun he takes from this spaceship.

Does anyone know the name of this anime?

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for the light novel and manga series, [*Ore ga Heroine o Tasukesugite Sekai ga Little Mokushiroku!?*](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=70424)

[image: Heroine overdose!!]

Comment: You are awsome. I am sorry I said anime. You hit it right on the head.

Comment: @Eric If you feel that this helped you,  you should click the check mark on the left of the answer.